# CASE Expression with Dates conditional Logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a logic in a query for a report that determines the number of days passed, excluding weekends.  There are 2 possible start dates - the original receipt date or the date of a re-submit (if it exists).  I am able to correctly calculate this using the following `CASE` statement

```
  CASE WHEN [ResubmitReceivedDate] IS NULL THEN
  (SELECT
        (DATEDIFF(dd, [OriginalReceivedDate] , [AnalysisDate]) + 1)
        -(DATEDIFF(wk,[OriginalReceivedDate] , [AnalysisDate]) * 2)
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [OriginalReceivedDate] ) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [AnalysisDate]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    )
    ELSE
    (SELECT
        (DATEDIFF(dd, [ResubmitReceivedDate], [AnalysisDate]) + 1)
        -(DATEDIFF(wk, [ResubmitReceivedDate], [AnalysisDate]) * 2)
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [ResubmitReceivedDate]) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, [AnalysisDate]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
    )
```

However, there are some instances when the `[AnalysisDate]` comes before the `[ResubmitReceivedDate]`, and in these instances, the `[OriginalReceivedDate]` should still be used even though a `[ResubmitReceivedDate]` exists.

How can I add this logic to the above `CASE` statement?

Comment: Not an answer, just some comments. (1) CASE is an expression, not a statement - those semantics can sometimes be very important. (2) Please, please, please stop using lazy shorthand like `dd` and `dw` - see [this post](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Updated title accordingly.  As for your second point, duly noted.  I didn't know you could use the full `datepart` name in the `DATEDIFF`, I thought the abbreviations were necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the simplest solution would just be to add another `When` condition. Something like this:

```
WHEN DateDiff(day, [ResubmitReceivedDate], [AnalysisDate]) > -1 THEN
    (Select
        (DATEDIFF(day, [OriginalReceivedDate] , [AnalysisDate]) + 1)
        -(DATEDIFF(week,[OriginalReceivedDate] , [AnalysisDate]) * 2)
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [OriginalReceivedDate] ) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [AnalysisDate]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    )
```

Which would make your final case

```
Case
     WHEN [ResubmitReceivedDate] IS NULL THEN
        (Select
            (DATEDIFF(day, [OriginalReceivedDate] , [AnalysisDate]) + 1)
            -(DATEDIFF(week,[OriginalReceivedDate] , [AnalysisDate]) * 2)
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [OriginalReceivedDate] ) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [AnalysisDate]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        )
     WHEN DateDiff(day, [ResubmitReceivedDate], [AnalysisDate]) < -1 THEN
        (Select
            (DATEDIFF(day, [OriginalReceivedDate] , [AnalysisDate]) + 1)
            -(DATEDIFF(week,[OriginalReceivedDate] , [AnalysisDate]) * 2)
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [OriginalReceivedDate] ) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [AnalysisDate]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
        )
    Else
        (SELECT
            (DATEDIFF(day, [ResubmitReceivedDate], [AnalysisDate]) + 1)
            -(DATEDIFF(week, [ResubmitReceivedDate], [AnalysisDate]) * 2)
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [ResubmitReceivedDate]) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
            -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(weekday, [AnalysisDate]) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
        )
End
```

Comment: Perfect!  The only thing that needs to be changed is that this line `WHEN DateDiff(day, [ResubmitReceivedDate], [AnalysisDate]) > -1 THEN` should be `... < -1` instead :)